# trying to modify the jQuery code to show files in a seperate tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery Plugin

https://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-fileTree/demo/ for a jquerytree, which works fine with this code

```
$('#drivestree').fileTree({
    root: "",
    script: 'includes/jqueryFileTree.php'
    }, function(file) { 
        alert( $('#drivestree a[rel="'+file+'"]').text() );
});
```

but I want to click directory and show the files in a different panel, I am able to do the directory to show me only the dirs and now I am trying to create a link on the directory which will call the class which triggers the load function to load files of that folder but the directory is clicked but no event fired

```
$(document).on('click','.showfiles',function() {
    $("#mainfilesarea").load('includes/filestypes.cfm?dir='+$(this).data('id'),'#mainfilesarea');
})
```

the event never gets fired:

```
<ul class="jqueryFileTree" style="">

            <li class="directory collapsed showfiles"><a data-id="c:/$Recycle.Bin" rel="c:/$Recycle.Bin/">$Recycle.Bin</a></li>


            <li class="directory collapsed showfiles"><a data-id="c:/story" rel="c:/story/">story</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the class showFiles is the < li > tag. The data-attribute where you store your directory record is at the < a > tag.

You need to navigate to the < a > element with .find, use this code;

```
$(document).on('click','.showfiles',function() {
    var data_id = $(this).find('a').data('id');
    $("#mainfilesarea").load('includes/filestypes.cfm?dir='+data_id,'#mainfilesarea');
});
```

Comment: it is not firing on that too, it never calls that

Comment: i think we need to modify the code which handles the plugin functionality, which is here in this paaste to handle the link

https://pastebin.com/xqDHcQwB